# Generic Type array with UITableView and Realm

Tags: swift, realm

I am using realm for database. I have Favourite Object and History Object.

I want to show in TableViewController. However, I don't want to do duplicated code. For now, in `FavouriteViewController` , it has `var favs: Results<OGFav>?` and `HistoryViewController`, it has `var history: Results<OGHistory>?`

Most of the code are the same and different is data type.

Example: it only different like following

```
if let object:OGFav = self.favs?[indexPath.row] {
```

In some place , I use like

```
let fav:OGFav = favs[indexPath.row]
```

For History

```
if let object:OGHistory = self.history?[indexPath.row] {
```

History also use like below

```
let history:OGHistory = self.history[indexPath.row]
```

How can I clean the code ? I am using two viewcontroller and code are the same excepted OGFav and OGHistory.

Update:

OGFav and OGHistory have the same data.

```
class OGFav: Object {

    dynamic var word = ""
    dynamic var def = ""

}

class OGHistory: Object {

    dynamic var word = ""
    dynamic var def = ""
    dynamic var updatedAt = NSDate()

}
```

Comment: make OGFav and History implement specific protocol and use that type

Comment: @Lu_ like data source for tableview ?

Comment: more like tableElement for arrays that you are using in datasource

Comment: have same data type and differentiate using string field? is that possible